# Angular AsyncValidatorFn works only onblur and not on keypress event

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using one of the latest angular version and I am trying to create a custom validation for validating a code thought a RestAPI, the example below works fine but **it doesn't work on keypress event**, it works only onblur event.
The "Code not available" text comes out only when the input field lose the focus. do you have any idea?

thanks in advance for your help!

this is the formbuilder

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      code: ['',
        [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9]{4}')],
        this.asyncCodeValidator.validate(),
      ]
    });
```

this is the asyncCodeValidator service

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AsyncCodeValidatorService {
  constructor(private codeService: CampaignService) {}

  validate(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      return this.searchCode(control.value).pipe(
        map(result => {
          return result.available ? null : { notUnique: 'Action code not unique' };
        })
      );
    };
  }

  searcCode(code: string): Observable<CodeValidate> {
    return timer(500).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.codeService.validateCode(code); // return Observable<CodeValidate> 
      })
    );
  }
}
```

this is the html control

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
       <input type="text" formControlName="code">

      <p style="color: red" *ngIf="form.get('code').errors?.notUnique">code not available</p>
</form>
```

using

```
    "@angular/common": "11.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "11.2.12",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution the error was on the changeStrategy.OnPush of the component